# Linux command: search all the commands I entered

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu.

there is a way to get a list of all the commands I entered that starts with the word: "git"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use history and awk together.

`history | awk '$2 ~ /^git/ { print }'`

Use `$2` or `$3` depending on the output of your history command.  As Andreas pointed out, it depends on the shell that you are using.  In bash, it will not include the time stamp.  This can be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: `history` prints the time stamp at the beginning of the line, so `^` does not match

Comment: @Andreas We could use `awk` then. Do you mean time stamp or number?

Comment: Well, both of them :) `history` prints something like `111  8:28    git status`, means that the line is at least not starting with `git`

Comment: @Andreas Updated, now that should work better!

Comment: +1 Excellent - good catch on using either $2 or $3, you could mention that it primarily depends on the shell

Answer (score 4):

You can either do an interactive backwards search with `Ctrl+R` or search your history with

```
history| egrep git
```

Answer (score 1):

to know what entered in linux shell

```
$ history | grep 'git'
```